# cherrypy 2.3.0 compatibale with Python 2.7.5?

Tags: centos7, cherrypy

How can I get cherrypy 2.3.0 to be compatible with Python 2.7.5? I am trying to run the Filelocker2 application. It is previously on an older server that is running centos 5. We created a new Centos 7 VM server, and are migrating Filelocker2 over to the new cent7 machine. However I am not able to find much info on this subject. I believe it must either be extremely simple so there isn't much documentation on it, or it's simply not possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[Screenshot of the error message I receive when executing the python startup script for Filelocker2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeeh4.png)

Comment: In what ways it's not compatible? What errors have you got?

Comment: I just edited my post and added a screenshot of the error message. Thank you.

Comment: What versions of Filelocker2 and CherryPy have you installed?

Comment: Filelocker2.6, and CherryPy 2.3.0 are the versions currently installed

Answer (score 0):

FileLocker 2.6 [requires](https://sourceforge.net/p/filelocker2/git/ci/master/tree/INSTALL.txt#l9) CherryPy 3.2+.

But I'm not sure you really have FileLocker 2.6. There is no such code in  [lib.FileFieldStorage](https://sourceforge.net/p/filelocker2/git/ci/master/tree/lib/FileFieldStorage.py). You have to find out what versions you really have.

Comment: I was looking in the /lib directory along with config files and came across an INSTALL.txt file and inside it shows "Filelocker 2.6 setup" so I am assuming it's running Filelocker2.6.